# Using a legacy google drive client inside a new firebase project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-drive-api

I have an app in production with several thousand users who use the google drive API to load files into a soundboard.

I'm releasing a new feature with a large firebase project that was unwittingly created with a different project than the google drive API uses in production.   When connecting google drive, beta users are greeted with a message "This app is blocked",  despite the client id being verified in production and both projects using the same app bundle id.

Is it impossible to use the old client Id?  If so, I would hate to delay my release several months while I wait for a new client Id to be reverified using the exact same info.  Is there any to have the existing client id moved into the new project without reverifying?  Or perhaps there is a way for client ID to have the approval expedited?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was using the scope of "drive.readonly" instead of just "drive" in my code after updating a third party cocoapod.    This simple error causes the “app is blocked” message!